# Android Studio Gradle build error- Task :app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug FAILED

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, gradle

I am new to android studio and Gradle. I have a project where I am loading a large SQLite database (from assets folder). When I press run and select an emulator, android studio starts on the build and executes gradle tasks. I am getting an error on one of these tasks which says:

```
     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'.
    > org.gradle.tooling.BuildException (no error message)
```

and in the complete error output in console it says this:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'.
    > org.gradle.tooling.BuildException (no error message)

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
    --debug option to get more log output.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 21s
```

I don't know if this is due to the large database. This is the stack trace of  the tasks being built:

```
     Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

    :app:buildInfoDebugLoader
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugSources
    :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug FAILED
    :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable Instant Run feature. Instruction for latest stable Android Studio:
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> [Remove checkbox] ""Enable Instant Run to hot sap code...""